# Cut part of string using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a unique case where I must join two tables based on text field. (Which is horibble I know)

The thing is that the join column in one table is:

ColumnA

```
Amz-g-r-t
Amz-g-r2-t
Amz-g1-r-t-x
```

and in the second table the column might contains more values in the same rows:

ColumnB

```
Amz-g-r-t not to ship
Amz-g-r2-t OK
Amz-g1-r-t-x
```

Basicly I wanna do:

```
select *
from A
join B on (a.ColumnA=b.ColumnB)
```

but it won't work because of the data in B.
So I need a way to remove all chars from B rows after the first space.
So ColumnB will be:

```
Amz-g-r-t
Amz-g-r2-t
Amz-g1-r-t-x
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what version of pg?

Comment: @EvanCarroll PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: It sounds like everything separate by a `-` is significant. I would consider breaking them out into their own columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**split_part()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function.

```
select *
from A
join B on a.ColumnA=split_part(b.ColumnB, ' ', 1)
```

> split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int) Split string on
> delimiter and return the given field (counting from one)

Performance would be poor not only because column are of text type but also because of using function on joining column which makes query **Non - SARGABLE**

Comment: You can always create an index on `split_part(b.ColumnB, ' ', 1)`